# Strange behavior in Vue 3 without any error or warning

Tags: vue.js

I have the following Vue 3 component that I am using in 2 pages that are setup like this in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    // Put this in the ASP.NET Core directory
    outputDir: "../wwwroot/app",
    pages: {
        vehicleDetails: "src/VehicleDetails.js",
        driverDetails: "src/DriverDetails.js"
  }
};
```

Both of these pages work and share the same underlying 'Certificates' component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3 id="Vue_Certificates">Certificates</h3>
        <div>
            objectId: {{objectId}} test

            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed2" style="clear: both;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><b>test</b></th>
                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                            <a href="#" @click="addCertificate">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add
                            </a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="certificate in certificates" v-bind:key="certificate">
                        <td>{{ certificate.CertificateTypeId }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" @click="removeCertificate(index)" title="Delete" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import _ from 'lodash';

    export default {
        components: {
            
        },
        props: {
            objectId: String,
            ownerIsVehicle: Boolean
        },
        data() {
            return {
                certificates: [],
                types: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            const requestOne = axios.get("/api/v1.0/CertificateType/GetCertificateTypes");
            const requestTwo = axios.get("/api/v1.0/Certificate/GetCertificateByObjectId", { params: { objectId: this.objectId, ownerIsVehicle: this.ownerIsVehicle } });

            axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
                const responseOne = responses[0];
                const responseTwo = responses[1];

                alert("Axios calls completed 1");

                this.types = responseOne.data;

                var mappedData = responseTwo.data.map(x => ({
                    ...x,
                    ValidFrom: new Date(x.ValidFrom),
                    ValidTill: new Date(x.ValidTill)
                }));

                this.certificates = mappedData;

                alert("Axios calls completed 2");

                console.log("succes");
            })).catch(errors => {
                console.log("fail");
            });
        },
        methods: {
            removeCertificate(index) {
                this.certificates.splice(index, 1);
            },
            addCertificate() {
                alert("Hello?");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The above code does NOT render the Vue component, but once I take out the two cells containing the anchors that call addCertificate & removeCertificate it all suddenly works.
For some reason I don't get any error in Chrome dev tools .. npm console .. visual studio console .. nowhere, so I have no clue at all what is going wrong.

**Important: If I take out 1 of the 2 lines in vue.config.js it works on the page that is still added.** The purpose of this component is that it can be reused.

FYI: I shrank down the code as much as possible to make sure other code bits aren't the cause.
For the record,  the data property "certificates" was first a ref([]) but that doesn't seem to help at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly does not work mean? Is there blank screen? The component isn't rendered? It's rendered but doesn't behave correctly? Possible problems are `(new Date()).addDays(10)`, `'` in template attributes, the availability of `$t`, `certificate` isn't a valid key because it's an object.

Comment: I've modified the question. Quick reply; I removed the $t as it was still a leftover of the code shrinking :) and it is just the component that does not get rendered. The rest of the page loads.

Comment: Also replaced the single quotes by double quotes in the template as you suggested + replaced the (new Date()).addDays(10) by just new Date() ... still the same problem.

Comment: If I remove 1 of the 2 lines in vue.config.js ... it all works on the page that is still added ... does this help?

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. I don't see how the question can be answered in its current state. If the problem is in cells, consider isolating the problem there. There likely won't be a problem with empty cells, will it?